# Creating instance of an object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, class, instance

I have this code:

```
  createNewDice = () =>{
    let dice;
    for(var i=0; i < 6; i++){
      dice[i] = new Dice();
    }
    console.log(dice, 'dice')
  }
```

when I call the method I get an error `Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Is this not the way to create a new instance of my class?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the property to an undefined variable so before trying to define property initialize variable as an array.

```
let dice = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize dice as an array first.

```
createNewDice = () =>{
  let dice = [];
  for(var i=0; i < 6; i++){
    dice[i] = new Dice();
  }
  console.log(dice, 'dice')
}
```

Edit for comment -

If you want to name them then do what Pranav suggested in using an object.  I would possibly take a different approach than Pranav suggested though and do something along the lines of -

```
const dice = {
  one: new Dice();
  two: new Dice();
  ...
  six: new Dice();
};
```

Comment: also how would I name it ? e.g. diceOne, diceTwo etc

Comment: @Theworm : use an object and define property name with `diceOne`, `diceTwo`, etc...